# Performance metric for categorical outcome prediction

Tags: r, prediction, model-evaluation

I have 3 independent subjects each of whom have one attempt at guessing the number of balls in a hidden tray with 20 compartments. Each subject therefore has to produce 20 guesses, one for each compartment. The number of balls in each compartment is an integer beginning at 0 with no upper limit (although the majority of the compartments have fewer than 10 balls). What are several ways of measuring the performance of each subject in predicting the actual number of balls. Note that I have no specific criteria in mind as to what is the most important feature in their predictive ability. I am open to suggestions.

Some dummy data in R:

```
actual_numballs <- c(4,2,3,3,3,4,3,7,5,3,3,3,2,3,2,2,3,3,4,8) # number in each of the 20 compartments
s1_predict_numballs <- c(4,2,2,3,2,4,3,7,5,3,3,3,2,3,2,2,3,3,2,9)
s2_predict_numballs <- c(3,2,2,3,2,4,3,5,5,3,3,3,2,3,1,2,3,3,2,3)
s3_predict_numballs <- c(4,2,3,3,3,4,3,7,5,3,3,3,2,3,2,2,3,3,2,3)
```

Now, I want to extend this so that the same subjects are now trying to guess the number of balls in the 20 compartments of several different trays, all of which are unrelated (independent) of eachother. How can I summarize the performance of the subjects across trays?

By the way, any solutions provided in R would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your outcome does not seem like a categorical one. It is a count.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways. First, your data aren't really "categorical" - they are counts. So:

1. You could just sum the absolute differences
2. You could take the median absolute difference
3. You could use least squares - that is, sum or average the squared distances

In `R` (there are doubtless better ways to program this):

```
actual_numballs <- c(4,2,3,3,3,4,3,7,5,3,3,3,2,3,2,2,3,3,4,8) # number in each of the 20 compartments
s1_predict_numballs <- c(4,2,2,3,2,4,3,7,5,3,3,3,2,3,2,2,3,3,2,9)
s2_predict_numballs <- c(3,2,2,3,2,4,3,5,5,3,3,3,2,3,1,2,3,3,2,3)
s3_predict_numballs <- c(4,2,3,3,3,4,3,7,5,3,3,3,2,3,2,2,3,3,2,3)

s1diff <- s1_predict_numballs - actual_numballs
s1abdiff <- abs(s1diff)
meds1abdiff <- quantile(s1abdiff,.5)
sums1abdiff <- sum(s1abdiff)
s1sqdiff <- s1diff ^2
sums1sqdiff <- sum(s1sqdiff)
means1sqdiff <- mean(s1sqdiff)
```